# Python - Recursive anagram function

Tags: python, recursion, anagram

I am working on a homework assignment, and am a little stuck and could use some help please.

I don't want the answer handed to me, but if I could get some help or tips I would greatly appreciate it.

I have to create a anagram generator that makes only 1 recursive function call and no for loops.

```
def anagram(st): 
if len(st) == 0:
    return []
else:
    if len(st) > 1:
        print(st)
        return [st] + [st[0]] + anagram(st[1:])
    else:
        print("test2",st)
        return [st[1:] + st[0]]

ana = anagram('abc')
```

This is my results: ['abc', 'a', 'bc', 'b', 'c'] 5

The answer should be: ['abc', 'acb', 'bac', 'bca', 'cab', 'cba'] 6

Comment: You can simply use `permutations` from `itertools`: `list(map(''.join, (permutations('abc'))))`.

Comment: @LevZakharov Not the point - OP gave clear constraints, because it's a homework assignment, and we have to respect them.

Comment: @LevZakharov I'm not allowed to use tools like that. I have to use 1 recursive function call to complete this assignment

Comment: I meant that you can look at `permutations` [implementation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) from python documentation.

Comment: Can you use comprehensions? Because doing it entirely loopless might not be trivial.

Comment: @Amadan I'm honestly not to sure...

Comment: @Amadan I might be able to use a loop outside of the recursive function call, but he was very clear to only use recursion functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's think without code for a bit, starting with a general case. Say you already know the permutations of `"bc"`, and they are `["bc", "cb"]`. How do you add `"a"` to the mix? I'd take each of the elements generated so far, and inserted `a` in each position. So, take `"bc"`, and inserting `"a"` in each position, you get `["abc", "bac", "bca"]`. Then do the same with `"cb"`. This leads us to the base case: since each recursion multiplies the number of results, the number of results in the base case must be 1, not 0, because when we iterate over solutions of the previous level, you would not be able to append anything, as nothing is there. So, `anagrams("")` must return `[""]` (so that inserting `"c"` later puts it into the only position it can).

Unfortunately, that's already two loops we're talking about (even with general recursive nature of the algorithm): one that iterates over `["cb", "bc"]`, and one that iterates over the positions to insert `"a"`. If you can use comprehensions, you can do this rather easily. If you can't, well... every loop can be rewritten into recursion, so... let me think a bit more.

Comment: def anagram(st):
    if st == '':
        return ['']
    lout = [ ]
    for i in range(len(st)):
        st2 = st[:i]+st[i+1:]
        lout2 = anagram(st2)
        for w in lout2:
            lout.append(st[i]+w)
    return lout

Comment: There is an anagram generator in the notes for Lecture 2. Write
a different anagram generator that makes only one recursive call instead of n
recursive calls as is done by the program in the notes. Set up an experiment to
2
compare the running times of the two programs. Produce a table showing your
results. Carry out the calculations until you see a difference in the results or
until you have exhausted the resources necessary to run the anagram generator.
Describe your results, and project the future behavior of these two algorithms.

Comment: Sorry for the messy code in the first comment. I didn't really know how to format it within the comments. And the second comment is the question he is asking us.

Comment: Let me note that you do have loops in your given code :P The task doesn't say "don't have loops", just "don't make recursive call more than once per function invocation". My algorithm fits this restriction.

Comment: That code in this comment is the code he wants us to transform into the 1 recursive call. Idk if that changes anything in your algorithm

Comment: It does not. It is very similar, but note that my recursive call is outside the two loops. Try to implement it. Also, you are right - code in comments is horrible, Python code even more so; so if you have a code-related update, edit the question and append the new stuff (and you can post a comment to alert people of the update).

Comment: I'm not too great at programming just yet but this homework is due soon, so I will just have to turn in what I got and just have to learn this for the next time. Thanks for the help

Comment: You can do it! Okay, more direct hint then: if the string is empty, return array containing an empty string. Otherwise, separate the string into the first character and the remainder, and initialise an empty list of results; see what anagrams you have from remainder, then for each of those, and for each position in range up to length of the input string (which is, remember, one more than the length of the rest of the string), insert the first character into the corresponding position of the remainder string, and append this concatenation to the result array. Then return the result array.

Comment: I'm too tired to try and figure it out lol. I've been working on this for a few hours and wasn't able to get it. I really appreciate the help and I did learn a lot. Hopefully I can get it to work.